# is it true that $\forall p < q : \mathbb E [ |X|^q ] < \infty \implies \mathbb E [ |X|^p ] < \infty $

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$$\forall p < q : \mathbb E [ |X|^q ] < \infty \implies  \mathbb E [ |X|^p ] < \infty $$

there is this post : [Show that if $\mathbb E(|X|^q)<\infty$ then $\mathbb E(|X|^p)<\infty$, for $p<q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2126240/show-that-if-mathbb-exq-infty-then-mathbb-exp-infty-for-pq)

but I don't understand the hint : show that $$ | X |^p < | X |^q + 1 $$ since we are integrating over reals and constants aren't $L^1$.

Can someone be more explicit please :) ?

Comment: Constants are indeed $L^1$ when integrated against a probability measure.

Comment: What? I ve never studied other measures than the classic one equal to the length.

Comment: OK, without measure theory language, they are saying that $|X|^p<|X|^q+1$ so $\int |x|^p f_X(x) dx < \int (|x|^q+1) f_X(x) dx$.

Comment: Oh... I see ^^' thanks!

Comment: Well, not exactly, because the measure doesn't have to be absolutely continuous, but $\int |x|^p \mu_X(dx) \leq \int (|x|^q+1)\mu_X(dx)$ does hold.

Comment: @Jakobian I think $X$ is implicitly assumed to be continuously distributed, but it would be better if that were explicitly stated in this post rather than gated behind a link.

Comment: Well i don't know if it is continuous, i m assuming the less possible. I m asking in total generality.

Comment: $E[a] = \int_{\Omega} a dP = aP(\Omega) = a$ from definition of Lebesgue integral. $a = \text{const.}$. In general the result you're trying to prove isn't true, and it pretty much relies on the fact that constants are $L^1$

Comment: @MarineGalantin Dealing with total generality requires some measure theory. You can separately handle the discrete and continuous cases without measure theory, but any generality beyond that basically forces it, or something essentially equivalent to it. In the end the statement "$L^p(\mu) \subset L^q(\mu)$ whenever $p>q$" is equivalent to "constants are $L^1(\mu)$", for any measure $\mu$. And the reason is the inequality $|X|^p \leq |X|^q+1$ or an analogous inequality e.g. $|X|^p \leq \max \{ |X|^q,1 \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using Jensen inequality, if $q>p>0$, then 
  $$\left(\mathbb E[|X|^p]\right)^{\frac{q}{p}}\leq \mathbb E[|X|^q].$$
  So indeed, $$\mathbb E[|X|^q]<\infty \implies \mathbb E[|X|^p]<\infty .$$
- More generally, if $\mu$ is a finite measure on a space $\Omega $ (i.e. $\mu(\Omega )<\infty $) then $$L^p(\Omega ,\mu)\subset L^q(\Omega ,\mu),$$
  for all $0<p<q$ which can be proved using Jensen as well.

Comment: What s the link between inclusion of L_p spaces and expectancy? Moreover the integral is usually taken over the real line, i don't see any link

Comment: @MarineGalantin : It really does : a probability space $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ is a measure space and $$L^p(\Omega ):=L^p(\Omega ,\mathbb P)=\{X:\Omega \to \mathbb R\mid X\text{ measurable and }\mathbb E[|X|^p]<\infty \}.$$ Remember that $$\mathbb E[|X|^p]:=\left(\int_\Omega |X|^p\,\mathrm d \mathbb P\right)^\frac{1}{p}=\|X\|_{L^p}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Without some further restriction on $p$ and $q$ the implication is not correct.
For  example, if $p=-1$ and $q=1$ we have $p<q$, but if $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ the claim is that since $\int_0^1 x\,dx<\infty$ we also have $\int_0^1 (1/x)\,dx<\infty$.

With the added assumption that $0\le p< q$ the hinted answer is correct.  (Because for all random variables $X$ and $Y$ with $P(0\le X\le Y)=1$ we have
$EX\le EY$, and because if $P(X=1)=1$ then $EX=1$.)